# Using Huggingface Transformer Models in R

Tags: r, huggingface-transformers, reticulate

I am trying to use different Huggingface models in R.
This works by importing the transformers package through reticulate (thank you, https://rpubs.com/eR_ic/transfoRmers)

Models where inputs just require a single string work for me.
Some models require a lists or a vector and I simply don't know where to get the information on how exactly to call the model.

Take this model for example. https://huggingface.co/openai/clip-vit-base-patch32.
From the python example I know it takes a picture and (I assume) a character vector of possible classes.
The Python input is: `text=["a photo of a cat", "a photo of a dog"], images=image`

```
library(reticulate)
library(here)
library(tidyverse)
transformers <- reticulate::import("transformers")
image_classification_zero_shot <- transformers$pipeline(task = "zero-shot-image-classification", model = "openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")
image_classification <- transformers$pipeline(task = "image-classification", model = "microsoft/beit-base-patch16-224-pt22k-ft22k")

image_url <- "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
```

The model just requiring the image works

```
image_classification(images = image_url)
```

The model which also requires a character input with the classes does not work.

```
image_classification_zero_shot(text = c("cats", "dogs"), images = image_url)
image_classification_zero_shot(text = "[cats, dogs]", images = image_url)

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
   TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

View(image_classification_zero_shot) does not yield any information.

1. How do I get the zero shot model to work?
2. How do I generally get the information on how to call these models in R? It's a function, shouldn't I be able to find information about its parameters somewhere (in R or on huggingface)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing a similar issue with another huggingface transformer called "jonas/sdg_classifier_osdg".

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not 
BatchEncoding
```

**Solutions**:

1. To write python code within a rmarkdown notebook
2. Activate repl_python() on the console and then write python code.

The same code generates a tensor when written in python but a character string when written in R.

**Further Questions**:

How to effectively transform an R string into a tensor that its understood by pythorch? (When I try to load torch together with reticulate, R crashes)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33724326)