# R equivalent for python brackets

Tags: python, r, huggingface-transformers

This is related to my earlier question ([Using Huggingspace Transformer Models in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74240029/using-huggingspace-transformer-models-in-r)) but I don't seem to have done a good job on the question. Here is another try.

I´m using transformer models from huggingspace in R. All models work fine except for models which require multiple strings as input. In python the syntax is ["a", "b"]. What is the equivalent in R? Quick research on my part resulted in vector/list, but those don´t seem to work.

This is the input in python which I am trying to replicate:

```
text=["a photo of a cat", "a photo of a dog"], images=image
```

Here is the R code

```
library(reticulate)
library(here)
library(tidyverse)
transformers <- reticulate::import("transformers")
image_classification_zero_shot <- transformers$pipeline(task = "zero-shot-image-classification", model = "openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")
image_url <- "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"

# all of those dont work
image_classification_zero_shot(text = c("a", "b"), images = image_url)
image_classification_zero_shot(text = "a,b", images = image_url)
image_classification_zero_shot(text = list("a", "b"), images = image_url)
image_classification_zero_shot(text = "['a', 'b']", images = image_url)
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly you are trying to create a vector of character in terms or R. There is a function `c()` to do this. Note, that there is no such thing as scalar variable in R. Scalars are dealt as vectors of length 1.

**Appended**

Sometimes functions in R are waiting for a pseudoscalar parameter (vector of length 1). In these cases vectorizing of such functions may be useful. For function

```
foo <- function(x) {
Some actions
return(something)
}
```

call with vectorization may look like:

```
Vectorize(foo)(x)
```

Comment: My problem is that the function does not accept c("a", "b") or list("a", "b") which were my ideas to substitute ["a", "b"] from python.

Comment: @qwertzuiop I've appended my answer with vectorization option. If it is not useful it seems you need to look for an absolutely different approach in your code.